# Should ng-bootstrap 8.x.x be prompting for entryComponents?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap, angular10

I'm updating an Angluar app from v9.1.x to v10.2.x, and subsequently updating ng-bootstrap to 8.x.x.  Since doing so, modals stopped working, and I'm getting an error message in the browser console asking if the component in question is listed as an `entryComponent`

Is this expected behavior?  From what I understand, `entryComponents` in Angular 9+ is no longer needed, and indeed, when we were running Angluar v9.1.x and ng-bootstrap v6.x we didn't need it.

This is a yes or no question really, so I don't know what debugging code I can provide other than something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // components
  ],
  imports: [
    // imports
  ],
  providers: [
    // providers
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    TestComponent // <-- this used to not be required by ng-bootstrap, and it not required by Angular 9x+
                  //     but any calls to NgbModal.open generate an error asking if the TestComponent is in the entry components
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the documentation - not sure how I missed it before.  The answer is yes - when you want to open a modal with a component as the contents, the component needs to be in the `entryComponent` list of your Angular module.

> You can pass an existing component as content of the modal window. In this case remember to add content component as an entryComponents section of your NgModule.

Source: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component

Sample app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/h7vehb--run?file=package.json

Their sample app is running Angluar 10.x, and ng-bootstrap 8.0